# Why is this AsParallel operation throwing a data provider error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, task-parallel-library, plinq

Thanks for looking.  I have the following return statement:

```
            //Return the result set
            return new FilterDto.FilterResult<Application>
            {
                Count = count,
                Results = _results.ToList().AsParallel().Select(s => ConstructApplication(s))
            };
```

Which calls the following method:

```
public Application ConstructApplication(Application application)
        {
            var result = new Application
            {
                Id = application.Id,
                Title = application.Title,
                Icon = application.Icon   
              
                   . . .
             
            };
            
            return result;
        }
```

The `AsParallel()` call is throwing the "underlying provider failed to open" error; a problem that has been fairly well documented when `AsParallel()` is used with the Entity Framework.

## Question

Since I am calling `ToList()` before `AsEnumerable()`, shouldn't my collection be thread safe since it is now an in-memory collection?

Comment: Can you check inner exception. Because Code seems to be fine. From error i think there is problem with connection String. Also try to remove AsParallel and check is it working.

Comment: @RohitHarkhani Thank you, the code runs fine without the `AsParallel()` bit.  Here is the inner exception:  "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting."

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that some of the properties in the constructor I call are lazy-loaded, so I needed to eager-load them before calling `AsParallel()` and the constructor using, for example, `.Include(i => i.Image)`.

Interestingly, my query was much faster with eager-loading the related entities, even without the use of `AsParallel()`.